# iOS: releasing NSString Object, that reads data from sqlite database

Tags: ios, database, release

I have an app that reads from sqlite database, and then shows the content in a button after each clicking the button.

```
 NSString *data;    
 query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM %@ WHERE ID=%d",TABLENAME,tempIndex];
 sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB,[query UTF8String],-1,&statement,NULL);
 sqlite3_step(statement);
 data = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
 sqlite3_finalize(statement);
 [myButton setTitle:data forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [data release];
```

However, the data never shows in the button and there is an error saying:

```
Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: _CFXMLNodeGetInfoPtr
```

If I do not release data, the app runs OK

Comment: To be clear, if you remove the release (last line of your code) the button displays the title and there is no message logged to the console?

Comment: yes, if I do not have the line `[data release]`, code runs fine

Comment: What happens if you do an autorelease?

Comment: I will try it now, never tried auto release before. How to do auto release in my case, btw?

Comment: `data = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)] autorelease];` works for me. Does it guarantee that it will release data object?

Comment: Yes that's how to do autorelease and yes the object will be released sometime later

Comment: It guarantees that it will behave properly with regards to memory management. The most important thing is that you've obeyed the [memory management rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html) and relinquished ownership of `data` - you needn't worry about exactly when it gets deallocated.

Comment: this code is running on the UI thread?

Comment: @CSmith: what does that mean by running on the UI thread? there is only one thread in my app

Comment: @CarlVeazey: the app works fine now with autorelease, if you formally answer my question in the answer section, I will mark your answer. Thanks

Comment: @DavidNG thanks. I really am stumped as to what's happening here though! Glad autorelease has got your app working though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is very strange behavior and I'd love to get to the bottom of it. But for now, autorelease your data string.

data = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)] autorelease]

Comment: I could not find the bug either, but at least yours solves my problem now. I will try to debug it if I have time.

Comment: I've favorited the question so will keep an eye on any new developments. And Glad I could help.